# Are there any entire functions that have a finite number of non-zero terms in their Taylor expansions?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, taylor-expansion

Besides polynomials, of course.

I am pretty sure the answer will be "no", but can we actually prove this?

Thanks,

Comment: What about polynomials?

Comment: @ClementC. OP excluded polynomials.

Comment: Arf, I need eyes.

Comment: Yes, I mean analytic everywhere, e.g., the sine and cosine functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entire functions agree everywhere with their Taylor series. If the Taylor series has only finitely many terms that are nonzero, then the function is (quite nearly by definition) a polynomial. There are non-analytic smooth functions which *do* satisfy the condition that their Taylor series has only finitely many nonzero terms in their Taylor series. An example is

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-1/x}, & x > 0 \\ 0 & x \le 0\end{cases}.$$

Its Taylor series at $0$ is zero and so it has finitely many nonzero terms (none!).

Comment: Ah, I meet this special function once again.  Great answer @cameronwilliams - thanks so much.

Comment: Haha yes it's very standard. I hate the example because I have flashbacks from real analysis proving the above result but it is a nice, simply stated example. Unfortunately it's hard to come up with a lot of specific examples in smooth function theory that aren't analytic.. since we love analytic things. You're very welcome.

Comment: Nice. +1. One can learn something here every day, it seems.